# PHP gmdate() returning UTC time an hour behind

Tags: php

So I have a problem whereby when I use the php `gmdate()` function on my local machine web server it returns the correct UTC time but when I upload the same script to a vps server the function returns a UTC time that is about and hour behind.I am using the UTC time together with javascript to display local time to different clients.

This is how i have called the function:

```
gmdate('m/d/Y H:i:s', time());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the server's timezone or even the default PHP timezone. You can override this using the following function `date_default_timezone_set()`

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

You can find a list of supported timezone identifiers here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Found out that since we were using a vps the person responsible for managing it had not configured the server machine time correctly

Answer (score 1):

Set your `date_default_timezone_set()` using PHP

Eg:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok"); // use your local timezone here
echo date_default_timezone_get();
?>
```

for more click here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php